# SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I'm a non profit lawyer trying to set up a SQL Server database for my agency. The issue I'm having is query based: I need a simple query that will aggregate the total number of rows on a table, not the sum of the cell contents.

I working with 4 columns of I to: attorney's name, client name, trial date and remedy (the last 2 are date and dollar amount, so integers].

```
 *** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS***
 SELECT TOP 100
 [attorney]
,[client]
,[trial_date]
,[remedy]
 FROM [MyLegalDB]
 WHERE [trial_date] between '20160101' and '20160531'
```

I'm trying to find a way (script, batch file, etc) that will populate a total number of cases by month (according to trial date) total number of clients, and sum the remedy column.

Sorry for the vagueness. There are privilege rules in place. Hope that helps clarify.

Thanks

Comment: For the total rows you can use the count() function in SQL. Do something like select count(*) from table

Comment: also SSMS has options to output queries to a text file or csv for excel

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: select attorney, year(trail_date) as Year, month(trail_date) as Month, count(*) as CaseCount, count(distinct client) as ClientCount, sum(remedy) as RemedyTotal
from MyLegalDB
where trial_date between '20160101' and '20160531'
group by attorney, year(trail_date), month(trail_date)

Comment: There are no *privilege rules* in place that prevent you from asking a specific, non-vague technical question. Privilege applies to what you're allowed to disclose about your clients, and nothing in this question would require specific client details. Even if sample client names *were* needed (which they're not), they could be generic, such as *Bob Smith*, *Jane Doe*, etc. You could have asked this question without referencing attorney or client or remedy, in fact. Don't claim privilege to try to cover a low-quality effort to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your case history spans years, not just months, try this:

```
 SELECT
,YEAR([trial_date]) AS [Year]
,MONTH([trial_date]) AS [Month]
,COUNT(1) AS [Trial_Count]
 FROM [MyLegalDB]
 WHERE [trial_date] between '20160101' and '20160531'
GROUP BY YEAR([trial_date]), MONTH([trial_date])
```

If you want to separate this by attorney, you would need to add that column to the `SELECT` list, as well as the `GROUP BY` clause, as such:

```
 SELECT
 [attorney]
,YEAR([trial_date]) AS [Year]
,MONTH([trial_date]) AS [Month]
,COUNT(1) AS [Trial_Count]
 FROM [MyLegalDB]
 WHERE [trial_date] between '20160101' and '20160531'
GROUP BY [attorney], YEAR([trial_date]), MONTH([trial_date])
```

This is a very general answer to a very general question.  If you want me to be more specific, I'm going to have to understand your goal a little better.  Hope it helps.